# How to implement a grid that can be expanded vertically and horizontally and shrinked again in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface

I need to implement a grid that can be expanded horizontally and vertically. It could look like this:

```
x-x
x-x

or 

x-x
x-x
x-x

or 
x-x-x
 x-x
x-x-x
```

x is a widget that can be added and removed. How can i implement this kind of feature?

You must be able to scroll as well as zoom in and out.